Interactive: systemctl on boot not the same as systemctl via CLI!
I want to execute an interactive session on the console via systemctl on boot up.
My .service file looks something like this:
[Unit]
Description=My service.
Requires=getty@.service network-online.target
After=getty@.service network-online.target multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash.bash -c '/usr/bin/nano /scripts/my_notes.txt'
Environment="TERM=xterm-256color"
Environment="SHELL=/bin/bash.bash"
StandardInput=tty-force
StandardOuput=tty
StandardError=tty
TTYPath=/dev/ttyLP0
TTYReset=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

So here's where things get weird (to me).  If I run this manually as root with systemctl start my_stuff.service, it opens up nano and everything works fine.
If I reboot the unit and wait, it opens up nano but arrow keys add junk to the file and don't move the cursor!
Why would this be any different then running it via systemctl "manually"?
In all cases I'm accessing the unit via serial console.
What gives?  Thank you for your help!

At system startup, processes are run as root (UID 0). In your terminal, processes are run as $USER (UID id -u). Early in system startup, the TERM environment variable has a different value ($TERM tells what kind of terminal you have, and $TERM leads to a definition of what cursor motion commands may be used).

Good call, however in this case I was running these as root manually.  I'll update the post.
Regarding the $TERM comments - is there an "After=" I should be setting so this works correctly?

The comments make no sense. Environment variables are not a global resource that changes over time. If you've set TERM to "xterm-256color" for your process then it will have the value of "xterm-256color" for your process no matter when it's started.

That being said, why is this a type=oneshot service? Why does it require getty@? That's not a valid unit name anyway, for one (you can only depend on specific instances, not on "all possible instances"), but if it were valid it would be the opposite of what you'd want – the task doesn't require getty, rather, it inherently conflicts with what getty is doing.

Just to confirm, the .service file starts with a [Unit] line before the Description line? I'm sure it does, but if not none of the Requires or After lines will be looked at.

@u1686_grawity, ultimately it'll be an interactive script which runs and ends with a reboot; testing with nano to ensure arrow keys work.  What I was going for was, the script requires tty stuff to be up (as it's interactive via the console) and requires networking.  What should my Requires= and After= look like?

@ErikF, yes, good call!  It does start with [Unit] - I missed it in the original post.  It's updated now.

@ZaPaDoS: tty stuff is always up. Getty isn't the "tty service"; it's the "login prompter" service. Its only use here might be the serial line speed setting or autodetection, but if you want that, then you'd need to have getty run your program, not to have both running concurrently (and both reading from the same tty concurrently!)

@u1686_grawity, ahhh, gotcha.  Hmmm so after some more investigation, I'm seeing things spit out in nano like A or 0 when using up arrow, or B or 0 when using down arrow, or chunks of it, so it does seem like my arrow key escape sequence is being eaten by some other tty.  Any thoughts on how I can structure this so that doesn't happen?

This is what ended up working for me.

My script service file:
[Unit]
Description=My service.
Conflicts=getty@ttyLP0.service
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash.bash -c '/usr/bin/nano /scripts/my_notes.txt'
Environment="TERM=xterm-256color"
StandardInput=tty-force
StandardOuput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
TTYPath=/dev/ttyLP0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


The getty service file:
[Unit]
After=my_script.service



